# Force Remove-NetNat

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

Is there a way to run the command remove-netnat without the need of confirmation?

I can't find any switch allowing me to force the deletion of a NAT configuraiton.

```
Remove-NetNat
```

Results into:

```
Bestätigung
Möchten Sie diese Aktion wirklich ausführen?
Der Vorgang "Delete" wird für den Richtlinienspeicher "Local" des Ziels "Test2" ausgeführt.
[J] Ja  [A] Ja, alle  [N] Nein  [K] Nein, keine  [H] Anhalten  [?] Hilfe (Standard ist "J"):
```

My expected result is the deletion of all or one NAT configuration without a confirmation question.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by using the `-Confirm` switch:

```
Remove-NetNat -Confirm:$false
```

[See here for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netnat/remove-netnatexternaladdress?view=win10-ps#optional-parameters)

Comment: I can't make the edit but the syntax here is wrong it should be: `Remove-NetNat -Confirm:$false`